# how to upgrade drupal 7 organic group version

Tags: drupal-7

I am using drupal 7 and running Organic Groups 7.x-1.4 and wanted to upgrade the Organic Groups version to 7.x-2.0. Can any one help. I have already taken the Db Backup

Answer (score 0):

- First, backup your database and current og module folder;
- Put your site in maintenance mode;
- To avoid complications, disable additional organic groups modules, like groups register, groups UI, etc... ;
- Install the modules dependencies required by og version 2 - message, message_notify, entityreference, entityreference_prepopulate, migrate;
- Copy the content of og 2 folder and paste into your og installed module folder overriding the files;
- Run drupal update;
- Follow the update instructions and if there is no error, access "content/migrate" and execute it to finalize the process.
- Lastly, check if your content is ok :)